# Holder continuity of Fourier transform of measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to prove the following, say $\mu$ is a non-negative Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mu(\mathbb{R}) = 1$ and 
$$ f(t) = \widehat{\mu}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{itx}\;d\mu(x).$$
Assuming that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x|^{2+\delta}\;d\mu(x) < \infty$$
Can we show that $f\in \mathrm{C}^{2,\delta}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: I would start with $f''(t)-f''(t+c) = \int_{|x| < c^{-r}}+\int_{|x| > c^{-r}} x^2e^{itx} (e^{icx}-1) d\mu(x)$ $= O( \int |x|^2 c^{1-r} d\mu(x))+O(\int_{|x| > c^{-r}} |x|^2 d\mu(x))$